# Does であるため mean "due to" or "for" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, translation

> 大臣認定に係る性能評価は、申請材料の仕様に対する評価であるため、「商品名」は記載しない でください。

Does in this case 「X であるため」 mean "for X" (in the sense of "when doing X") rather than "due to"? Here's my attempt:

> According to the quality evaluation approved by the minister, for the
>   evaluation of the specifications of the requested materials, don't
>   write the "trade name".

Also, could you check the rest of my translation? I'm not sure about the value of the first 「は」 which I translated as "according to". Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, "ため" in "であるため" means "because."

I'm not 100% sure as the context is not clear, but it is likely that the sentence has the following structure:

> (大臣認定に係る性能評価は、申請材料の仕様に対する評価である)ため、「商品名」は記載しない でください。

So the role of "は" is simply a subject marker.

Now the whole translation would be:

> Since the quality evaluation *related to* approval by the minister is an evaluation of the specifications of the applied materials, do not write the "trade name".

So roughly speaking, this is saying that the evaluation is not for a product but for materials used for it.

An additional note is that I translated "係る" to "related to".

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I also noticed that you translated 申請材料 into "applied materials", does it mean that they are materials for which an evaluation has been requested (for example by a company)?

Comment: @Marco Sorry my translation was not so good. Yes, 申請材料 means materials for which an evaluation has been requested.